# What object to return in the following arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to understand array list and have read and searched online for a few examples. I am unable to understand what OBJECT should this arraylist return? I know the arraylist has object type `user`. On returning it I encounter the following error
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Boolean to User`

```
private ArrayList<User> users; // list of users

public User createUser(String name, String address) {
        user = new ArrayList<User>();

        users.add(new User(name, address));

        return null; <-- not sure what to return here
    }
```

Also `User` is another class.

```
public class User {

    private String name; // user name
    private String address; 

    /*
     * constructor method
     */

    public User(String name, String address) {
        // initialize the instance variables
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
```

Comment: Well, your method expects that you should return a single `User` instance.  But you have a ***list*** of `User`s.  What are you supposed to return?

Comment: The following is what i am expected to return
`This method creates a User object, adds it to the user ArrayList and returns the object.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being this

```
public User createUser(String name, String address)
```

your method signature, you must return an object of type `User` or one of its subclasses.

I think this is what you're trying to achieve

```
private ArrayList<User> users; // list of users

public User createUser(String name, String address) {

    User u = new User(name, address);
    users = new ArrayList<User>();

    users.add(u);

    return u;
}
```

but notice that by executing

```
users = new ArrayList<User>();
```

inside the method, you will *reset* the list every time: you will always have a list of one element. Initialize your list only once, instead

```
private ArrayList<User> users= new ArrayList<User>(); // list of users

public User createUser(String name, String address) {
    User u = new User(name, address);
    users.add(u);
    return u;
}
```

Comment: So I want to add 10 users. How can I achieve that? If I initialize `users = new ArrayList<User>();` in the constructor. Will it still reset the list everytime?

Comment: Sure you can initialize it inside the constructor, as long as it's executed only once